# Combine two rows with different values

Tags: sql, oracle

When I try to run the following query

```
SELECT product_code, 
       COUNT(*) FROM PRODUCT
 WHERE product_line = 'IRON'
 GROUP BY product_code;
```

I am getting the following output

```
product_code | count(*)
-----------------------------
IRON(A)      |         25
IRON(B)      |         50
IRON(C)      |         50
IRON(D)      |         100
```

I need to combine row 1 and row 4. After that, I am expecting something like this

```
product_code | count(*)
---------------------------
IRON(A)      |         125
IRON(B)      |         50
IRON(C)      |         50
```

Please help me regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the condition to combine rows ?

Comment: How on earth are we supposed to know that IRON(A) is combined with IRON(D). If you were sat next to someone and asked them the question what do you imagine the response would be ?

Comment: You need to have at least something in common between row 1 and 4 so you will be able to combine then... Otherwise you can't.

Comment: What is the original data _before_ grouping in `product_line`?

Comment: Ok then assume that we have IRON(A) = 100 instead of IRON(D) = 100. Now is it possible to combine both rows?

Comment: You need sum `IRON(A)` and `IRON(D)` and display summed value as count of `IRON(A)` ?

Comment: What is it that makes you want to combine 'IRON(A)'  and 'IRON(D)'? Why not 'IRON(B)'  and 'IRON(C)` for instance?

Comment: @MohsinALvi: If IRON(A) = 100 and IRON(A) = 25, then your original query will return IRON(A) = 125.

Comment: Thorsten Kettner, i change the scenario to change IRON(D) to IRON(A). Its a requirement and i need to insert both values as one in another table.

Comment: @Nitish: Its not my original query. It is my expected query.

Comment: The question is still unclear to me. Instead of adding comments, please edit the question to show the actual sample data and needed result, also explaining the logic behind your expected result

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you need just combine `IRON(A)` and `IRON(D)` and display summed value as count of `IRON(A)`, then :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN product_code = 'IRON(D)' 
            THEN 'IRON(A)' 
            ELSE  product_code 
            END AS product_code, 
       COUNT(*) 
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE product_line = 'IRON'
GROUP BY CASE WHEN product_code = 'IRON(D)' 
              THEN 'IRON(A)' 
              ELSE product_code 
              END AS product_code;
```